# Show Link by IP range

Tags: customer, javascript, script, locations, js-css

I have a magento store that also has a link labeled 'shop local' that a customer can click to get information on our one retail location.

As we only have one store in one state, I would like to somehow only show that link if a customers IP is from the appropriate state.   I would prefer a way with CSS, but realize this probably requires js.  Thanks in advance.

Pleas note: our ecommerce store is open to all of the US.  So the reason to hide the link for other 49 states is to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to go is with **GeoIP**.
GeoIP is a database that holds geolocation infos.

There are [paid versions](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-databases) but also [free ones](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/).

You can use various extensions to interact with GeoIP, for example [Sandfox_GeoIP](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Sandfox_GeoIP).

---

Update: according to the comments below I added some sample-code for getting/setting the country info.
While adding the answers I found there's also a [GeoIP JavaScript API](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/). You might also want to have a look at this.

First: **There is no possibility to detect a IP or state with CSS only.**

**Solution 1: Hide via CSS**

Add the CSS if required (check for state) in your template file (.phtml):

```
<?php $geoip; // some GeoIP-model you can access ?>
<a href="http://linktoshoplocal.com" class="shoplocal <?php echo $geoip->getState()!="FL" ? "hide" : ""; ?>">shop local</a>
```

Please note: `$geoip->getState()` is just a sample method here. Replace it with the specific method of your GeoIP implementation.

Your css class needs to be:

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

**Solution 2: Do not output link (better approach than 1)**

```
<?php $geoip; // some GeoIP-model you can access ?>
<?php if($geoip->getState()=="FL"): ?>
   <a href="http://linktoshoplocal.com" class="shoplocal">shop local</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

No CSS rule is required here, as the link will only be in the output if the state matches.

**Solution 3: Use the GeoIP JavaScript API**

1. Load GeoIP JavaScript API
2. Add a `onload` event to your document
3. Check with GeoIP API if a state is set, if not, remove/hide link via JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you.  I am aware of GeoIP, and use for customer order location. However, my question is relating more to the code in the form of js or CSS that could create the desired result.

Comment: It will be a bit hard to help you with CSS if we don't know your HTML+id's and classes. There are 2 options: 1.) output the link and add a .hide class which has display:none for states where you don't want to show it, 2.) better approach: only add the link to your HTML via template for the relevant states.
Both options require a check for the state(s) via PHP. But without some code samples, it's not possible to provide a specific answer.

Comment: Yes, option 1 is the idea I've had as far as the display:none is concerned.  However, I've searched high and low on how to have a css rule that checks for IP or even just State.  If you are able to provide that info, the rest I can handle and mark this solved.

Comment: see my updated answer.